# Protractor - fields present but not visible - Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, jasmine, protractor

I've only just started with Protractor.

This is my problem:

I want to log in to a website. When the page loads, it displays a spinning loading wheel before displaying the Username and Password fields, and a Sign in button.
My problem is that any attempts to `clear()` or `sendKeys()` fail because the fields are not yet visible on the screen, and protractor is trying to interact with them.

> InvalidElementStateError: invalid element state: Element is not
>   currently interactable and may not be manipulated.

What I have noticed is in the page source initially the spinning wheel has `class='ngscope'` and after a while it changes to `class='ng-scope ng-hide'`

The whole thing is this:

```
<div ng-show="Model.Busy" class="ng-scope ng-hide">
    <div ng-class="{'control--inline': small, 'div-centre': !small}" class="div-centre">
    <img ng-src="/assets/img/loading.gif" ng-class="{'very-small-loading': small}" src="/assets/img/loading.gif">
</div>
</div>
```

The piece of code that I'm using is:

```
describe('Testing', function() {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

  var username = element(by.model('Model.Username'));
  var password = element(by.model('Model.Password'));
  var loginbutton = element(by.css('[ng-click="Model.Logon()"]'));


  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('MY WEBSITE');
  });

  it('should log me in', function() {

//  expect($('[ng-show=Model.Busy].ng-hide').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();  <-- this fails


    username.clear();
    password.clear()

    username.sendKeys('1');
    password.sendKeys('2');

    loginbutton.click();

  });
});
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait until the loading animation hides and then try to work on the elements that appear on the page using protractor's inbuilt `wait()` function. One way is to wait until an element shows up using [`presenceOf()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf) feature. Here's how -

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; //Its Kendo UI coupled with Angular, so ignore the angular load

//There are 2 login forms with same attributes so using by.model wouldn't work in this case
var username = $('#MainView .form-input[name="txtUsername"]');
var password = $('#MainView .form-input[name="txtPassword"]');
var loginbutton = $('[ng-click="Model.Logon()"]');
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(username), 20000).then(function(){
    username.clear().then(function(){
        username.sendKeys('1');
    });
    password.clear().then(function(){
        password.sendKeys('2');
    });
    loginbutton.click();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Girish. Unfortunately that didn't help. What happens now is the animation 'hangs' for the duration given in browser.wait (10s), and then I get the same error. It will be easier if I just give you the website address: https://client.compliancecentre.co.uk Please take a look, see if you are able to sendKeys to Username and Password and click the Sign in button... (note: the page may load really fast and the spinning wheel will be displayed only for a fraction of a second. but it is there)

Comment: @Alichino if that is the case then waiting for username or password field makes sense. Updated answer with this solution. I am not able to see the field at all, maybe automation on the webpage is disabled with some sort of javscript. Could you please check that?

Comment: @Alichino I was able to recreate your issue and seems like the webpage uses Kendo UI library on the client side. Updated the code to include the code that works. Let me know if you still have an issue. Thanks

Comment: I was able to log in now, thank you Girish. One thing, though - it kept screaming about ignoreSynchronization not being a function, so I've changed it to " = true " instead of (true) and it worked!

Comment: for anyone wondering as ignoreSynchronization  = true has been deprecated, waitForAngularEnabled=(false) is the replacement as of now